# replace $_GET with array of $userslist

Tags: php

im using this script through $_GET to add user name to my db beside it to my twitter list the script function well
for examlpe when i call it at url domain.com/add.php?user=username
the function of adding executed 100% fine
My doubt  is about adjust the code to add multi users at once through array or get list of user from file 
any tips to adjust the code or modify it ?

```
 <?php
session_start();

 require_once('dbconnect.php');
  require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
   require_once('config.php');

   $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET);

   $user = $_GET['user'];

 if( !isset( $_GET['user'] ) )
die('You must enter a username');


   $info = $connection->get( 'users/show', array("screen_name"=> $user
                                  ));   
$var = $_GET['user'];



 $individual = 1;

 $protected = ($info->protected == "true")?1:0;

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO tweeps VALUES('%s', '%s', %s, %s, '%s', '%s', '%s', %s ) ",
mysql_real_escape_string($info->screen_name),
mysql_real_escape_string($info->name),
$info->followers_count,
$info->statuses_count,
mysql_real_escape_string($info->location),
$info->created_at,
$info->profile_image_url,
$protected)    ;


  echo $query;      

$result = mysql_query($query); 
if(false) 
 echo "s";

 else {

$list_id = get_latest_list();
$list = "Tweeps-" . $list_id;

    echo "list $list";

mysql_free_result($result);
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET);

$result = $connection->post( 'friendships/create/' .  $info->screen_name    );  
//var_dump($result); die();
    $result = $connection->post( 'lists/members/create', array("screen_name"=>   $info->screen_name,
                                   "slug"=> $list,
                                       "owner_screen_name"=>  "Tweeps")  ); 

if( !isset($result->error) ) {

    $userid = $info->id;
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO followed_tweeps(screenname, userid, individual, list_id) VALUES('" . $info->screen_name . "', '" . $userid . "', $individual, $list_id)");       

}

 }
    echo "SUCCESS";





  function get_latest_list() {

$query = "SELECT count(*) cnt, list_id FROM followed_tweeps group by list_id order by  list_id desc";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if(! $result ) {
    die("Error: query is $query error is: " . mysql_error() );
}

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $cnt = $row[0];
    $free_slots = 500 - $cnt;   
    $list_id = ($freeslots > 0) ? $row[1]++ : $row[1];
    return $list_id;

  }


  ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

PHP supports an array notation for multiple same-name query parameters:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
                             ^^--- tells PHP to treat 'name' as an array
```

You can then process this as:

```
if (isset($_GET['name']) && isarray($_GET['name'])) {
   foreach ($_GET['name'] as $name) {
      ...
   }
}
```

This works regardless for both POST and GET - you just have to include the `[]` on the field name.

Comment: never knew I could do this, and what is the delimiter? or it treats as an array if I have many fields with the same name like
<input type="text" name="name[]" id="name1"/>
<input type="text" name="name[]" id="name2"/> ?

Comment: the same question how its gona treat it as array ?

Comment: when your form contains `<input type="text" name="name[]" /><input type="text" name="name[]" /><input type="text" name="name[]" />` your url will be `form.php?name[]=value2&name[]=value2&name[]=value3` PHP then automatically makes $_GET['name'] an array (accessed with a foreach loop or as $_GET['name'][0], $_GET['name'][1], etc